# How to test a method that depends on a before action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

Essentially I have the test and class below. I am trying to test the method `new`. but the problem is that method depends on the before action `set_variables` which is private and so I am not sure how to call it. I thought that it would've been called when I instantiated the class but it doesn't seem like it does.

Test:

```
require "test_helper"
class MyControllerTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "myTest" do
    controller = MyController.new()
    response = controller.new()
  end
end
```

the controller class:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_variables
  def new
    @other_variable = @my_variable.stuff.order(:name)
  end

  private

  def set_variables
    puts "setting variables"
    @my_variable = MyObject.find(params[:my_id])
  end
end
```

Comment: I mean that Controller code is just not a good idea.

Comment: @smathy It's a very cut down version of the actual code for simplicity, there's a lot more going on but it's essentially doing something like this.

Comment: @smathy the controller code is just a basic example of using a callback in Rails to DRY the setup of an instance variable. The problem here is that the test is fundamentially broken.

Comment: @max look again, the INSTANCE method `set_variables` needs to be called before the `new` method is called during instantiation. The code is inherently broken, not (just) the test.

Comment: @smathy. No. The `new` method has nothing to do with instanciation. It's just a standard action thats called when the router matches it to the new route.

Comment: Ha, that's funny, I'm such a dope. I've been switching languages too much recently, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2):

## That's not how it works.

> I thought that it would've been called when I instantiated the class but it doesn't seem like it does.

Callbacks are not called when a controller is instanciated. Controllers are instanciated by the router when it matches the incoming request. The router then calls the `dispatch` method on the controller which wraps the execution of the method on the controller with `run_callbacks` to ensure that the callbacks are run. See [ActiveSupport::Callbacks for a basic example of how callbacks work](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Callbacks.html).

What you're doing here is completely conceptually broken as Rails controllers are Rack applications and you can't just test them in isolation out of that context without mocking out pretty much the entire framework. It's just a plain old bad idea.

## You don't test methods - you test HTTP endpoints.

While you can use legacy approach of using `ActionController::TestCase` to write unit tests for your controllers with a mocked request this approach is known to be fundamentially flawed and is recommended against by the Rails team.

The currently accepted way of testing controllers is through [integration tests](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#integration-testing) which send real HTTP requests to the Rails application and on a higher level through [system tests](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#system-testing) which simulate a real user. After all what controllers really do is respond to incoming HTTP requests and tie everything together and faking the rest of the stack introduces the potential for all kinds of bugs to slip through.

```
require "test_helper"
class BarsFlowTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    @foo = foos(:one)
  end

  test "/foo/invalid_id/bars/new" do
    get new_foo_bar_path(foo_id: 'invalid_id')
    assert_response :not_found
  end

  test "/foo/:foo_id/bars/new" do
    get new_foo_bar_path(foo_id: @foo.id)
    # write assertions about the response 
  end
end
```

Comment: If you want a rundown of how Rails dispatches requests [Medium has a good article](https://medium.com/rubyinside/a-deep-dive-into-routing-and-controller-dispatch-in-rails-8bf58c2cf3b5). I don't want to link to it in the answer as they have a paywall.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to special test for before actions or stub them somehow, such edge cases are covered with simple controller tests (but I prefer to use rspec, so my examples will be for rspec), in your case they will be

```
context 'when object is not found' do
  it 'raises error', :aggregate_failures do
    expect { get :new, params: { id: 'unexisting' }}.to raise_error(ActiveRecord::NotFound)
    expect(response).not_to render_template :new
  end
end


context 'when object is found' do
  let!(:object) { create :object }

  it 'renders new template' do
    get :new, params: { id: object.id }

    expect(response).to render_template :new
  end
end
```

Often in controller tests you pass different sets of params and just validate responses of controller.

Answer (score -3):

To test the *new* method in your controller that depends on the private *set_variables* method, you can use a mocking library like *mocha* or *minitest-mock* to stub the *set_variables* method and set the *@my_variable* instance variable directly. Here's an example using *mocha*:

```
    test "myTest" do
      my_object = MyObject.find(1)
      MyController.any_instance.expects(:set_variables)
      controller = MyController.new()
      controller.instance_variable_set(:@my_variable, my_object)
      response = controller.new()
      assert_not_nil response.other_variable
    end
```

In this example, we are using *MyController.any_instance* to stub the *set_variables* method for all instances of *MyController*. We are also using *controller.instance_variable_set* to set the *@my_variable* instance variable directly. Finally, we are testing the *other_variable* instance variable to ensure that it is set correctly by the *new* action.

Comment: `controller = MyController.new(); response = controller.new()` - really? Did you try it?